# `-X patience` vs `-X diff-algorithm=patience` with `git merge-recursive`

Tags: git, git-merge, git-diff

What is the difference between

`git merge -s recursive -X patience other-branch
git merge -s recursive -X diff-algorithm=patience other-branch`

Also do either of

`git merge -s recursive -X patience -X diff-algorithm=patience other-branch
git merge -s recursive -X patience -X diff-algorithm=histogram other-branch`

mean anything. If so, what?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the difference between
>
> ```
> git merge -s recursive -X patience other-branch
> git merge -s recursive -X diff-algorithm=patience other-branch
> ```

None.  `-X patience` is an old name for `-X diff-algorithm=patience`, dating back to when there was only one alternative.  You can, currently, spell the histogram algorithm with `-X histogram` as well.  The only one requiring `-X diff-algorithm=` is `minimal`.

> Also do either of
>
> ```
> git merge -s recursive -X patience -X diff-algorithm=patience other-branch
> git merge -s recursive -X patience -X diff-algorithm=histogram other-branch
> ```
>
> mean anything. If so, what?

The last algorithm chosen on the command line overrides any previous ones on the command line, so these both have the effect of ignoring the first `-X` option.

(Note that `-s recursive` is the default strategy for merge when merging two commits, so this is redundant as well.  It doesn't *hurt*, it just makes no difference.)